# How to non-lethally capture a sapient gorilla using only what can be found in an average American kitchen?

Tags: weapons, low-fantasy, tactics, bootstrapping

I'm writing this story where a good friend of the main character gets kidnapped by a clan of sapient Gorilla-like creatures. In order to find where they are keeping him captive, the MC decides that the only way to know for sure is to capture a gorilla-like creature alive and interrogate it to find answers.

The following is true:

- The creature is about twice the size of a Gorilla, *"Gorilla beringei graueri,"* and is roughly as intelligent as a 12-year-old human pre-teen.
- The main character has special ops training and has access to anything that can be found in an average American kitchen.
- The gorilla must be reasonably contained to the point that it could not break free following several hours of intimidation/interrogation.
- The creature cannot be reasonably harmed during its capture.
- MC is not a human, but an elf. She has the same general build and capabilities as an adult human female but is 3 feet tall
- The gorilla has no knowledge of the original trap, but will actively be pressuring the main character before the trap is sprung.

Comment: "Twice the size of a gorilla". Like 10ft tall, 1000lbs? Does it fit in the kitchen? Does the actual scuffle happen in the kitchen, or is that just where supplies are gathered from? A nimble human may have an advantage against an encumbered beast in a room too small to move fluidly.

Comment: The creature in question is mostly bipedal and is around 8 feet tall and weighs about 900 pounds. 

The encounter takes place in a huge warehouse.

Now that I think about it, I think that it is also important to note that the MC is not a human, but an elf. She has the same general build and capabilities as a human but is 3 feet tall.

Comment: VTC:Too Story-Based. This isn't a worldbuilding question. It's a story-based question and depends on what you, the story-teller, places in the kitchen. (And I've been in enough American kitchens to know the phrase "average American kitchen" has little meaning.) Worldbuilding is about setting rules independent of all stories upon which stories are then built. Storybuilding is about plot, circumstances, and character choices (like what to use in a kitchen...). See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4):

### Capture

Offer the gorilla yummy baked goods that cause impressive diarrhea. Then turn on the TV.

- Easy enough: Just use a lot of cooking oil.

Result: The gorilla will simply shuttle between the kitchen and bathroom all day long. Maybe take a nap.

No intimidation necessary. Just alternate baked goods and hang on to the TV remote. "*Oh, you finished those very-chewy cookies? Well, when you get back let's dive into these very-moist brownies. Oh, and this show is really funny!*"

---

### Interrogate

Since the way the alien's mind and culture work are undisclosed, we'll use the models of a pubescent human here. It's quite possible that humans have NO useful way to influence or interrogate the alien. But let's assume that we do, and that it can be found in the kitchen.

Teasing answers out of 12-year-old-equivalents with treats and TV is not that difficult.

Just let them blather about themselves and their friends and their mates and their tribal politics. "*Stupid Jeff thinks he's so great*"

Suck up to them with how good they must be at keeping secrets. Make them feel important. Competent.

Or just bribe them: "*Here, have another brownie. Tell you what, you can have the whole pan right now if you help me with this little problem I'm having...*"

Comment: Most likely a gorilla would have very different reward mechanisms than seeing flashy lights to continue staying in the "trap". Also a sentient alien might not even decide to enter in the first place. Luring with food is doable, but the rest should probably be reworked.

Comment: @Vesper good point! Added a paragraph to assume somewhat human-like behavior and why.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Gain its trust**

Give it a banana or some other fruit. Poptarts will do.

**Step 2: The buttering**

Butter a portion of the floor, to facilitate the slipping of bipedal creatures. (Do not step on the butter yourself. However, if you do and don't bang your head too hard, the gorilla may find it to be amusing slapstick comedy and it will reinforce step 1. Just don't knock yourself out. Maybe wear a helmet? (Oh right this is a kitchen- Put a colander on your head.))

**Step 3: Make it slip**

Carefully get behind the butter zone, and then present another banana or pop tart. The gorilla will come towards you and slip on the butter.

**Step 4: Slip it pills**

When the gorilla slips, quickly peel the banana and embed Benadryl tablets in it. (Scale up the dose for a 1000lb person.) Console the gorilla and give it the snack.

**Step 5: Wait**

Digestion is a little slow. Entertain it for a bit while the antihistamines take effect. Soon it will start napping.

**Step 6: Bind it**

Bind the gorillas arms and legs with duct tape. (This is maybe a little atypical kitchen junk drawer fodder. Maybe you have kitchen twine for tying up a roast chicken. I figure you'd need a lot more of that than duct tape to be effective.)

**Step 7: Wait**

Maybe make yourself a snack while the gorilla processes the benadryl out of its system, or play wordle, or check StackExchange.

**Step 8: Interrogate**

(Hey it rhymes!)

Answer (score 2):

**Get the Gorilla Drunk**

A mental age of 12 and probably hasn't consumed alcohol before, get the Gorilla tipsy and ask them questions - in vino Veritas - in Wine, there is truth.

And someone who is Drunk for the first time is unlikely to have the tools or experience to be able to lie convincingly under the effects of Alcohol.

Then, like all first-time drunks, they keep going until they pass out - thus allowing for the 'capture'